# Accessing table from postgresql to R

Tags: r, postgresql

I have two database in postgresql. They are: (i) *postgresql* and (ii) *uppersacramento*.

I am trying to import table from these two databases to R. I got strange problem. My problem is: I can import table from *postgresql* successfully, but cannot import from *uppersacramento* database. Here is the code:

```
# I can get all iris data from postresql database to R with no problem
test <- dbGetQuery(con, 'SELECT * from iris') 

# Here I run into an error
test1 <- dbGetQuery(conSac, 'SELECT * from 20190502')
```

Here is the error:

> Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) :    RS-DBI
>   driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  syntax error at or
>   near "20190502" LINE 1: SELECT * from 20190502
>                         ^ ) Warning message: In postgresqlQuickSQL(conn, statement, ...) :   Could not create execute: SELECT * from 20190502

Please note that I can view all tables in *uppersacramento* database in R.
Also, I tried if there is any issue with the table name, which is all numbers, by changing table name to character also did not help.

Any clue?

Thanks

Comment: *by changing table name to character also did not help* ... Please explain this better. Do you mean you actually changed table names in Postgres to NOT start with numbers such as `T20190502` and you re-attempted the query in R with new name and it failed with SAME error? Please advise.

Comment: Thanks Parfait. I got it resolved. The issue was to use double quotation (") for table name.

Comment: I could have easily told you that. Better yet, avoid tables that start with numbers and include special characters. By the way a table with dated name suggests your database design is not optimizing relations and normalization. Don't use Postgres (an advanced RDBMS) as data dump from R, CSV, etc.!